# How to create a navbar using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, header, nav

Please suggest, what I am doing wrong? Below is the link of my code.

https://codepen.io/MadanSinha/pen/KKyxOaV?editors=0100

The problem that I am facing - I am not able to fix the position of the navbar (ul) and header logo (h1) in a single line after using the flex property, getting the ul items in the column within the row of h1.

- Why I am unable to use flexbox on navbar?
- Why after using flex properties navbar is not converted into row?
- Is there any simple way where I can put the header logo, navbar both together using flexbox?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;700&family=Pacifico&display=swap");

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:wght@200;500;600;700&display=swap");



*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#023E8A;
}

ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1{
  font-family:Pacifico;
}

.header{
  background-color:#D8E2DC;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:0.5rem;
  padding-bottom:.5rem;
  border:1px solid #E8E8E4;
  border-bottom-left-radius:8px ;
  border-bottom-right-radius:8px ;
  box-shadow:0 5px 10px #ECE4DB;
  position:sticky;
}

li{
  padding-top:.2rem;
  padding-bottom:.2rem;
}

.nav-bar{
  padding-top:.5rem;  
  font-family:Poppins;
  color:#FFE5D9;
  display:block;
}


/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */




@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .header,
    .main-nav {
        display: flex;
    }
    .header {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        .header{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1150px;
    }
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    .header {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></h1>
  
  <ul class="nav-bar">
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  
<header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change .nav-bar display to flex

```
.nav-bar{
  padding-top:.5rem;  
  font-family:Poppins;
  color:#FFE5D9;
  display:flex;
}
```

here is an updated fiddle :
https://codepen.io/digitalcaveman/pen/QWOXydd?editors=1100

Comment: Hello @ekay, thank you for letting me know but still all the navbar child elements are still closer to each other how I can set a spacing between them and fixed all the element end of the right side.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this [pen](https://codepen.io/neptotech/pen/PoOrpbw)

### Or this code

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;700&family=Pacifico&display=swap");

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:wght@200;500;600;700&display=swap");


:root{
  --justifyType:space-around;/*try space-between*/
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#023E8A;
}

ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  width:100%;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1{
  font-family:Pacifico;
}

.header{
  background-color:#D8E2DC;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:0.5rem;
  padding-bottom:.5rem;
  border:1px solid #E8E8E4;
  border-bottom-left-radius:8px ;
  border-bottom-right-radius:8px ;
  box-shadow:0 5px 10px #ECE4DB;
  position:sticky;
        display: flex;
}

li{
  padding-top:.2rem;
  padding-bottom:.2rem;
}

.nav-bar{
  padding-top:.5rem;  
  font-family:Poppins;
  color:#FFE5D9;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: var(--justifyType);
}


/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */




@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .header,.main-nav {
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: var(--justifyType);
    }
    .header {
        
        align-items: center;

justify-content: var(--justifyType);
    
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    .header {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: var(--justifyType);
    }

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></h1>
  
  <ul class="nav-bar">
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  
<header>
```

### This is an edit to @ekay 's answer!

- This makes space between (as per asked in comments)
- There are two types, currently its `space-around`, you can change to `space-between` if needed in `:root`
- we also set `ul`'s width to `100%`

Answer (score 0):

You just change the display to be like this.
.nav-bar{
display: flex
}

Comment: And erase all the other properties? Why?